# c# double[] binary array to js Float64Array via base64

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, base64, double

I am trying to send an encoded double[] array as a base64 string from C# server to typescript client.

The base64 is created like this:

```
double[] values = new double[]{...}
var bytes = values.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();
var stringToBeSent = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
```

And on the client i'm trying to decode it like this:

```
let binary_string =  atob(encodedString);
const byteNumbers = new Array(binary_string.length);
for (let i = 0; i < binary_string.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
}

const values = new Float64Array(byteNumbers);
return Array.from(values);
```

However, the values are very different from what i've sent. Did anybody encounter this problem? Is the Float64 format different from the C#'s double format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to decode the double[] values like this:

```
decodeFromBase64(encodedString: string): number[] {
    let binary_string = atob(encodedString);
    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binary_string.length);
    let bytes_buffer = new Uint8Array(buffer);

    for (let i = 0; i < binary_string.length; i++) {
      bytes_buffer[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }

   let values = new Float64Array(buffer);
   return Array.from(values); 
}
```